# ColdFusion 10 application.cfc error: counting number of active sessions

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

In the adobe coldfusion 10 documentation, [Defining the application and its event handlers in Application.cfc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d39.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0b63c-7ff1), there is a sample Application.cfc containing the function below. After looking at the code, I am wondering if there is a typo/bug in the following code:

```
<cffunction name="onSessionStart"> 
    ...
    <cflock timeout="5" throwontimeout="No" type="EXCLUSIVE" scope="SESSION"> 
        <cfset Application.sessions = Application.sessions + 1> 
    </cflock> 
    ...
</cffunction>
```

Should it be:

- (A) cflock ... scope="SESSION"
  or
- (B) cflock ... scope="APPLICATION"

?

If it is (A) then I am confused. Can someone explain why?

Comment: When onSessionStart is called automatically, it's thread safe. If you call it yourself, it isn't. That would be my reasoning for the lock in the first place. So my vote is that it's a typo and should be APPLICATION.

Comment: google `coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker`! I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [my answer to the same question asked on the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4524996#4524996):

> Don't be confused... it's an error in the docs.  You could do Adobe a
>   favour by commenting at the bottom of the page: they do monitor those
>   comments (they don't always react, but the do monitor them).
>   onSessionStart() is intrinsically single-threaded as far as the
>   session scope goes: it's only ever run once per session (when the
>   session starts...).   On the other hand the code in question def wants
>   to single-thread access to that application-scoped variable as we
>   don't want two simultaneous sessions hitting it for any given single
>   value of it (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

You always lock the SCOPE that you are writing to. In this case it would be APPLICATION.

Comment: Just to be clear: there are legitimate circumstances in which you also would want to lock a shared scope being read from, but this is not one of those occasions.  Also, it's not always essential to lock shared-scope writes.  In the given situation though, you are correct in that the wrong scope is being locked in the example code.